# How to fit the model GLM with a bimodal distribution

Tags: r, distributions, generalized-linear-model

Jerkrate is how many lunges (feeding attempts) a whale make along time based on a sudden change in acceleration (jerk). The distribution of jerk rate is negative bimodal.

I was forced to use gaussian in the following model but I am violating the assumptions because is not the correct distribution. How can I make the model work?

[image]

```
model <- glm(
  JerkRate~Noise.intensity+BoatEventType+TaggingEffect+Noise.intensity:BoatEventType,
  data=data,
  family=gaussian(link="identity")
  )
```

Comment: Note that the dependent variable isn't what needs to be normal, it's the residuals.  Those however won't be normal if you data is bounded between zero and one.  Look into beta regression.  If you DV is a proportion, it can sometimes make sense to use a logit in these situations.

Comment: 1. You show far too few bins in your histogram (avoid the R defaults; they're really not good for diagnostic purposes). 2. Tell us about the jerk variable; is it necessarily positive, for example? Is it bounded above (or if not, is it just happenstance that the largest values are just below 1?) 3. Don't worry about the marginal distribution of the variable, the assumptions are about the conditional distribution. It's quite possible for the marginal distribution to look bimodal when the conditional distribution is everywhere unimodal. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... 4. Why use `glm` if you're going to use the gaussian with the identity link? `lm` is at least as good in every way for that case -- and better in a couple of respects.